# Was time statistical?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, time, wick-rotation

In QFT the change to the Euclidean picture the $$\exp[iS]$$ looked like the partition function in statistical mechanics, and thereby the approaches in the statistical mechanics might be uaeful to that of the QFT and vise versa. One of which brought the time to the Lagrangian multiplier, temperature, in the close comparison.

Thus it brought the question that weather the direction of the time flow could be in fact a statistical phenomenon rather than an absolutist. Experimentally, there's also experiments in QM in recent years suggested the accidental backwards flow of entropy as an indication of the backward flow of the time, etc.

Question 1: Was time statistical?

Question 2: Question 1 might be a bit buzzard to those who's not interested in the foundation. However, here's the things that might matter. If the time to be seen as a Lagrangian multiplier, then where was the gauge fixing procedure that made the temporal flow to be the absolutist? For example, in EM field a gauge fixing $$\Delta_G(\partial_\mu A^\mu(x)-\omega(x))$$ was need to achieve photon propagator and to extract the finite value from the infinity. For the time to be flow in a particular direction, it might involve some sort of gauge, for example, $$\partial_\tau^2 T=0$$ that would reduce some infinity in the calculation as well, which was not seen in the previous QFT calculations.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that any sort of a confirmed insight into the fundamental nature of time / space-time beyond General Relativity would be the discovery of the century, and we all would have heard of it. So quite expectedly the answer to your question, OP, is "we don't know yet". You may find the "thermal time hypothesis" related to your thinking, but please be very aware of its *highly* speculative nature.

Comment: If it is, I hope that it is a power law with very fat tails.